# How to use char instead of varchar when generating db tables from entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using `string(32)` instead of `integer` for entity `id` field (it simulates guid type). But after creating database table from entity ids field type is set to `varchar(32)`. I think it's not the best idea, `guid` always has length = 32 so `char` type will be more appropriate.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to use `char` or the only way is to change it manually in database?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Although the *althaus* solution works fine I think this one should be the canonical way of doing it:

With annotations:

```php
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=2, options={"fixed" = true})
 */
protected $country;
```

With YAML (example of both ID and non-ID field):

```
Your\Nice\Entity:
    id:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 32
            options:
                fixed: true
    fields:
        country:
            type: string
            length: 2
            options:
                fixed: true
```

> - **options**: Array of additional options:
>
>   - `fixed`: Boolean value to determine if the specified length of a string column should be fixed or varying (applies only for string/binary column and might not be supported by all vendors).

[Official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)

Answer (score 7):

You can tell Doctrine to use vendor specific field types:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="CHAR(2) NOT NULL")
 */
protected $country;
```

[Source](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column)